# Android URI error java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider: http://

Tags: java, android, video, uri

I am creating something like a facebook post. Where a user can upload images and videos, and also view them. So I create an arrayList of the files and if the user click any image or video, it take them to a new activity to display all files in a viewpager, passing the arrayList and the index of the clicked file as parameters, so I can use the arrayList to set my adapter and the position of my viewpager to the index of the clicked file.

So here is my activity which displays the files

```
Bundle fileParams = getIntent().getExtras();
filePosition = fileParams.getInt("index");
allFiles = fileParams.getStringArrayList("arrayList");
photoOpenerAdapter = new PhotoOpenerAdapter(allFiles, cntxt);
viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
viewPager.setAdapter(photoOpenerAdapter);
viewPager.setCurrentItem(filePosition);
viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(allFiles.size());
viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
        viewPager.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                //loadedInitial is a boolean value to make this thread run only once
                if(!loadedInitial) {
                    loadedInitial = true;
                    String filePath = allFiles.get(position);
                    String fileType = functions.getmInstance(cntxt).checkFileType(filePath);
                    if(fileType == "video")
                        startVideoPlayer(position);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        pauseVideoPlayer();
        String filePath = allFiles.get(position);
        String fileType = functions.getmInstance(cntxt).checkFileType(filePath);
        if(fileType == "video") {
            startVideoPlayer(position);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
    }
});

private void pauseVideoPlayer() {
    if(!(videoView == null)){
        videoView.pause();
    }
}

public static void startVideoPlayer(int position) {
    View videoLayout = viewPager.getChildAt(position);
    videoView = (VideoView) videoLayout.findViewById(R.id.videoPlayer);
    if(!(videoView == null)) {
            videoView.requestFocus();
            videoView.start();
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the `instantiateItem` thread of my `PhotoOpenerAdapter.java` class

```
@NonNull
@Override
public Object instantiateItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, final int position) {
    layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    String imageUrl = postFilesLists.get(position);
    String fileType = functions.getmInstance(context).checkFileType(imageUrl.toLowerCase());
    if(fileType == "video") {
        view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.video_player, container, false);
        VideoView videoView = (VideoView) view.findViewById(R.id.videoPlayer);
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(imageUrl);
        videoView.setVideoURI(uri);
    } else{
        view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.photo_opener, container, false);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image);
        imageLoader.displayImage(imageUrl, imageView);
    }
    container.addView(view);
    return view;
}
```

This code works fine but when the `filePosition` is a video file, and I try to use the `onPageScrolled` thread to load the video Url, I get the error `java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider: http://` which is coming from the line `Uri uri = Uri.parse(imageUrl);`, but if the `filePosition` is an image file, and I scroll to a video file, `onPageSelected` plays the video successfully.

Please I don't what am doing wrong

Here is the complete **Stack Trace**

```
04/07 11:30:40: Launching 'app' on Pixel 2 API 29.
$ adb shell am start -n "com.pixtanta.app/com.pixtanta.app.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Waiting for process to come online...
Connected to process 2259 on device 'Pixel_2_API_29 [emulator-5554]'.
Capturing and displaying logcat messages from application. This behavior can be disabled in the "Logcat output" section of the "Debugger" settings page.
I/om.pixtanta.ap: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
W/om.pixtanta.ap: Suspending all threads took: 11.490ms
E/om.pixtanta.ap: Unknown bits set in runtime_flags: 0x8000
W/om.pixtanta.ap: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
I/MultiDex: VM with version 2.1.0 has multidex support
    Installing application
    VM has multidex support, MultiDex support library is disabled.
W/RenderThread: type=1400 audit(0.0:270): avc: denied { write } for name="property_service" dev="tmpfs" ino=6344 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c139,c256,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:property_socket:s0 tclass=sock_file permissive=0 app=com.pixtanta.app
D/libEGL: Emulator has host GPU support, qemu.gles is set to 1.
W/libc: Unable to set property "qemu.gles" to "1": connection failed; errno=13 (Permission denied)
D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libEGL_emulation.so
D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_emulation.so
D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_emulation.so
W/om.pixtanta.ap: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/View;->computeFitSystemWindows(Landroid/graphics/Rect;Landroid/graphics/Rect;)Z (greylist, reflection, allowed)
W/om.pixtanta.ap: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/ViewGroup;->makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows()V (greylist, reflection, allowed)
W/om.pixtanta.ap: Accessing hidden method Landroid/graphics/FontFamily;-><init>()V (greylist, reflection, allowed)
    Accessing hidden method Landroid/graphics/FontFamily;->addFontFromAssetManager(Landroid/content/res/AssetManager;Ljava/lang/String;IZIII[Landroid/graphics/fonts/FontVariationAxis;)Z (greylist, reflection, allowed)
    Accessing hidden method Landroid/graphics/FontFamily;->addFontFromBuffer(Ljava/nio/ByteBuffer;I[Landroid/graphics/fonts/FontVariationAxis;II)Z (greylist, reflection, allowed)
    Accessing hidden method Landroid/graphics/FontFamily;->freeze()Z (greylist, reflection, allowed)
    Accessing hidden method Landroid/graphics/FontFamily;->abortCreation()V (greylist, reflection, allowed)
    Accessing hidden method Landroid/graphics/Typeface;->createFromFamiliesWithDefault([Landroid/graphics/FontFamily;Ljava/lang/String;II)Landroid/graphics/Typeface; (greylist, reflection, allowed)
D/HostConnection: HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xdf3462d0, tid 2311
    HostComposition ext ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 ANDROID_EMU_direct_mem ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v1 ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v2 ANDROID_EMU_YUV420_888_to_NV21 ANDROID_EMU_YUV_Cache ANDROID_EMU_async_unmap_buffer GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr ANDROID_EMU_gles_max_version_2 
W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0xdf31a240: maj 2 min 0 rcv 2
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xdf31a240: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xdf30f110)
W/Gralloc3: mapper 3.x is not supported
D/HostConnection: createUnique: call
D/HostConnection: HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xdf346410, tid 2311
D/HostConnection: HostComposition ext ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 ANDROID_EMU_direct_mem ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v1 ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v2 ANDROID_EMU_YUV420_888_to_NV21 ANDROID_EMU_YUV_Cache ANDROID_EMU_async_unmap_buffer GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr ANDROID_EMU_gles_max_version_2 
D/eglCodecCommon: allocate: Ask for block of size 0x1000
    allocate: ioctl allocate returned offset 0x3ffff6000 size 0x2000
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xdf31a240: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xdf30f110)
I/om.pixtanta.ap: Background concurrent copying GC freed 4031(1010KB) AllocSpace objects, 2(40KB) LOS objects, 52% free, 1374KB/2910KB, paused 470us total 316.229ms
W/ActivityThread: handleWindowVisibility: no activity for token android.os.BinderProxy@5f8eb60
I/Choreographer: Skipped 34 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xdf31a240: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xdf30f110)
W/om.pixtanta.ap: Verification of java.lang.String okio.internal.ByteStringKt.commonHex(okio.ByteString) took 232.844ms
I/OpenGLRenderer: Davey! duration=1006ms; Flags=1, IntendedVsync=10885691977642, Vsync=10886258644286, OldestInputEvent=9223372036854775807, NewestInputEvent=0, HandleInputStart=10886267267970, AnimationStart=10886267414940, PerformTraversalsStart=10886268302090, DrawStart=10886442318860, SyncQueued=10886448317080, SyncStart=10886459965410, IssueDrawCommandsStart=10886460230610, SwapBuffers=10886678824180, FrameCompleted=10886710235330, DequeueBufferDuration=75000, QueueBufferDuration=573000, 
W/om.pixtanta.ap: Verification of java.lang.String okio.internal.ByteStringKt.commonToString(okio.ByteString) took 109.047ms
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xdf31a240: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xdf30f110)
I/chatty: uid=10139(com.pixtanta.app) RenderThread identical 2 lines
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xdf31a240: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xdf30f110)
W/om.pixtanta.ap: Verification of okio.Buffer okio.Buffer.writeUtf8(java.lang.String, int, int) took 103.361ms
W/om.pixtanta.ap: Accessing hidden method Lcom/android/org/conscrypt/OpenSSLSocketImpl;->setUseSessionTickets(Z)V (greylist,core-platform-api, reflection, allowed)
    Accessing hidden method Lcom/android/org/conscrypt/OpenSSLSocketImpl;->setHostname(Ljava/lang/String;)V (greylist,core-platform-api, reflection, allowed)
    Accessing hidden method Lcom/android/org/conscrypt/OpenSSLSocketImpl;->getAlpnSelectedProtocol()[B (greylist,core-platform-api, reflection, allowed)
    Accessing hidden method Lcom/android/org/conscrypt/OpenSSLSocketImpl;->setAlpnProtocols([B)V (greylist,core-platform-api, reflection, allowed)
W/om.pixtanta.ap: Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/CloseGuard;->get()Ldalvik/system/CloseGuard; (greylist,core-platform-api, reflection, allowed)
    Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/CloseGuard;->open(Ljava/lang/String;)V (greylist,core-platform-api, reflection, allowed)
    Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/CloseGuard;->warnIfOpen()V (greylist,core-platform-api, reflection, allowed)
D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
W/om.pixtanta.ap: Verification of okio.Source okhttp3.internal.http1.Http1ExchangeCodec.newUnknownLengthSource() took 106.135ms
I/om.pixtanta.ap: NativeAlloc concurrent copying GC freed 8287(782KB) AllocSpace objects, 7(140KB) LOS objects, 49% free, 2343KB/4686KB, paused 1.498ms total 225.137ms
W/System: A resource failed to call close. 
I/chatty: uid=10139(com.pixtanta.app) FinalizerDaemon identical 2 lines
W/System: A resource failed to call close. 
V/MediaHTTPService: MediaHTTPService(android.media.MediaHTTPService@5dd4fad): Cookies: null
    makeHTTPConnection: CookieManager created: java.net.CookieManager@a4fd2e2
    makeHTTPConnection(android.media.MediaHTTPService@5dd4fad): cookieHandler: java.net.CookieManager@a4fd2e2 Cookies: null
I/om.pixtanta.ap: NativeAlloc concurrent copying GC freed 4930(489KB) AllocSpace objects, 23(460KB) LOS objects, 49% free, 2754KB/5508KB, paused 3.218ms total 327.970ms
W/System: A resource failed to call close. 
I/chatty: uid=10139(com.pixtanta.app) FinalizerDaemon identical 2 lines
W/System: A resource failed to call close. 
I/om.pixtanta.ap: JIT allocated 70KB for compiled code of void android.view.View.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int, int)
W/System: A resource failed to call close. 
I/chatty: uid=10139(com.pixtanta.app) FinalizerDaemon identical 22 lines
W/System: A resource failed to call close. 
I/OpenGLRenderer: Davey! duration=1410ms; Flags=0, IntendedVsync=10888523779635, Vsync=10888923779619, OldestInputEvent=9223372036854775807, NewestInputEvent=0, HandleInputStart=10888932055650, AnimationStart=10888932332760, PerformTraversalsStart=10888932378740, DrawStart=10889814355560, SyncQueued=10889856339460, SyncStart=10889856637920, IssueDrawCommandsStart=10889859104780, SwapBuffers=10889924611950, FrameCompleted=10889935046350, DequeueBufferDuration=92000, QueueBufferDuration=1623000, 
I/om.pixtanta.ap: NativeAlloc concurrent copying GC freed 9429(653KB) AllocSpace objects, 15(300KB) LOS objects, 49% free, 3684KB/7369KB, paused 3.468ms total 426.579ms
W/System: A resource failed to call close. 
I/chatty: uid=10139(com.pixtanta.app) FinalizerDaemon identical 7 lines
W/System: A resource failed to call close. 
W/ActivityThread: handleWindowVisibility: no activity for token android.os.BinderProxy@49b7a99
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xdf31a240: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xdf30f110)
W/MediaPlayer: Couldn't open http://192.168.58.1/...
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider: http://192.168.58.1/uploads/video/PXT-IMG-1586206898-82ecc8ad45.mp4
        at android.content.ContentResolver.openTypedAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1673)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1503)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1420)
        at android.media.MediaPlayer.attemptDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1101)
        at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1073)
        at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1097)
        at android.widget.VideoView.openVideo(VideoView.java:412)
        at android.widget.VideoView.setVideoURI(VideoView.java:287)
        at android.widget.VideoView.setVideoURI(VideoView.java:270)
        at com.pixtanta.app.PhotoOpenerAct.startVideoPlayer(PhotoOpenerAct.java:102)
        at com.pixtanta.app.PhotoOpenerAct$1.onPageSelected(PhotoOpenerAct.java:76)
        at androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager.dispatchOnPageSelected(ViewPager.java:1947)
        at androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager.scrollToItem(ViewPager.java:686)
        at androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager.setCurrentItemInternal(ViewPager.java:670)
        at androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager.onTouchEvent(ViewPager.java:2263)
        at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:13415)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3054)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2741)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3060)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2755)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3060)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2755)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3060)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2755)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3060)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2755)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3060)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2755)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3060)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2755)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:465)
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1849)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:3993)
        at androidx.appcompat.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:69)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:423)
        at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:13674)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5482)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:5285)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4788)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4841)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4807)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4947)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4815)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:5004)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4788)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4841)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4807)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4815)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4788)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:7505)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:7474)
W/MediaPlayer:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:7435)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:7630)
        at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:188)
        at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
        at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:336)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:174)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
V/MediaHTTPService: MediaHTTPService(android.media.MediaHTTPService@983af96): Cookies: null
V/MediaHTTPService: makeHTTPConnection: CookieHandler (java.net.CookieManager@a4fd2e2) exists.
    makeHTTPConnection(android.media.MediaHTTPService@983af96): cookieHandler: java.net.CookieManager@a4fd2e2 Cookies: null
D/MediaPlayerNative: getMetadata
W/MediaPlayerNative: info/warning (3, 0)
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xdf31a240: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xdf30f110)
V/MediaPlayer: resetDrmState:  mDrmInfo=null mDrmProvisioningThread=null mPrepareDrmInProgress=false mActiveDrmScheme=false
    cleanDrmObj: mDrmObj=null mDrmSessionId=null
    resetDrmState:  mDrmInfo=null mDrmProvisioningThread=null mPrepareDrmInProgress=false mActiveDrmScheme=false
    cleanDrmObj: mDrmObj=null mDrmSessionId=null
W/ActivityThread: handleWindowVisibility: no activity for token android.os.BinderProxy@24b04a0
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xdf31a240: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xdf30f110)
Process 2259 terminated.
```

Comment: Please edit your question and post the entire stack trace. It is difficult to tell what line is giving you this error.

Comment: Add also information on which Andoid version you are testing (and that is target API)

Comment: @CommonsWare the error is coming for the line `Uri uri = Uri.parse(imageUrl);` and I only get the error when the file that is clicked, which its index is passed as a parameter to `filePosition` is a video file.

Comment: If the clicked file is an image file, and then I scroll to the next page which is a video file, I don't get the error

Comment: @Boken the API target is 29

Comment: "the error is coming for the line Uri uri = Uri.parse(imageUrl);" -- that is not possible. Please edit your question and post the entire stack trace.

Comment: Okay... Give me a moment please

Comment: @CommonsWare I have edited my question, show my complete stack trace

Comment: OK, the error is coming from `setVideoURI()`. My best guess is that the `http` scheme is your problem, as that is banned by default on Android 7.0+. Try using a public URL with an `https` scheme and see if it works.

Comment: @CommonsWare I am running my app on WAMP server. But then I don't get any error when `onPageSelected` is called, the video plays fine

Answer (score 0):

Finnaly I got it working... the problem was setting the ViewPager's current item before the ViewPager loaded the adapter. So I had to set that after the ViewPager has finished loading

```
    Bundle fileParams = getIntent().getExtras();
    filePosition = fileParams.getInt("index");
    allFiles = fileParams.getStringArrayList("arrayList");
    photoOpenerAdapter = new PhotoOpenerAdapter(allFiles, cntxt);
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
    viewPager.setAdapter(photoOpenerAdapter);
    //here I removed the viewPager.setCurrentItem(filePosition) to set it after the ViewPager has finished loading
    viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(allFiles.size());
    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
            viewPager.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if(!loadedInitial) {
                        loadedInitial = true;
                        String filePath = allFiles.get(position);
                        String fileType = functions.getmInstance(cntxt).checkFileType(filePath);
                        if(fileType == "video")
                            startVideoPlayer(position);
                        // here the ViewPager has finished loading so I call the method to implement the viewPager.setCurrentItem(filePosition)
                        setViewPagerCurrentItem();
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            pauseVideoPlayer();
            String filePath = allFiles.get(position);
            String fileType = functions.getmInstance(cntxt).checkFileType(filePath);
            if(fileType == "video") {
                videoView = null;
                startVideoPlayer(position);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
        }
    });

//Method to implement the viewPager.setCurrentItem(filePosition)
private void setViewPagerCurrentItem() {
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(filePosition);
}

private void pauseVideoPlayer() {
    if(!(videoView == null)){
        videoView.pause();
    }
}

public static void startVideoPlayer(int position) {
    View videoLayout = viewPager.getChildAt(position);
    videoView = (VideoView) videoLayout.findViewById(R.id.videoPlayer);
    if(!(videoView == null)) {
        videoView.requestFocus();
        videoView.start();
    }
}
```